# Counting maximum number repetition in a row using sql (laravel / mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I have data looking like this:

[image]

Is it possible to count using id as a column order (ASC) what is max value 0 occurrence in a ROW?
So expected result will be 0 was 3 times in a row; or if we count value 1 - 2 times in a row.

Well in php I could foreach all values and count occurences but i'm looking for solution to do that in database.

Kind regards 
Mark

Answer (score 1):

You can use some a gaps-and-island technique for this, using the difference between row numbers to build groups of consecutive records having the same value.

If `id`s are always incrementing by `1` (with no gaps):

```
select sl, max(no_rec)
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over(partition by sl, id - rn) no_rec
    from (
        select t.*, row_number() over(partition by sl order by id) rn
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by sl
```

Otherwise, we can generate a fake autoincremented id with `row_number()`:

```
select sl, max(no_rec)
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over(partition by sl, rn1 - rn2) no_rec
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            row_number() over(order by id) rn
            row_number() over(partition by sl order by id) rn
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by sl
```

Note: this uses window functions, which require MySQL 8.0. In earlier versions, such problem is much more cumbersome to solve.